# GWT resizable panel

Tags: gwt

Is there any way to have a 'Resizable' panel in GWT.

By resizable I mean that if you you drag on the edge of Panel it can be resized accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out myself, here is an example:

```java
public class DraggablePanel extends VerticalPanel {
    private boolean isBeingDragged = false;
    private boolean isBeingMoved = false;
    private Element movingPanelElement;

    public void setMovingPanelElement(Element movingPanelElement) {
        this.movingPanelElement = movingPanelElement;
    }

    public DraggablePanel() {
        super();
        DOM.sinkEvents(getElement(), Event.ONMOUSEDOWN | Event.ONMOUSEMOVE
                | Event.ONMOUSEUP | Event.ONMOUSEOVER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        final int eventType = DOM.eventGetType(event);
        if (Event.ONMOUSEOVER == eventType) {
            if (isCursorResize(event)) {
                getElement().getStyle().setProperty("cursor", "s-resize");
            } else if (isCursorMove(event)) {
                getElement().getStyle().setProperty("cursor", "move");
            } else {
                getElement().getStyle().setProperty("cursor", "default");
            }
        }
        if (Event.ONMOUSEDOWN == eventType) {
            if (isCursorResize(event)) {
                if (!isBeingDragged) {
                    isBeingDragged = true;
                    DOM.setCapture(getElement());
                }
            } else if (isCursorMove(event)) {
                DOM.setCapture(getElement());
                isBeingMoved = true;
            }
        } else if (Event.ONMOUSEMOVE == eventType) {
            if (!isCursorResize(event) && !isCursorMove(event)) {
                getElement().getStyle().setProperty("cursor", "default");
            }
            if (isBeingDragged) {
                int currentY = event.getClientY();
                int originalY = getElement().getAbsoluteTop();
                if (currentY > originalY) {
                    Integer height = currentY - originalY;
                    this.setHeight(height + "px");
                }
            } else if (isBeingMoved) {
                RootPanel.get().setWidgetPosition(this,
                        event.getClientX(), event.getClientY());
            }
        } else if (Event.ONMOUSEUP == eventType) {
            if (isBeingMoved) {
                isBeingMoved = false;
                DOM.releaseCapture(getElement());
            }
            if (isBeingDragged) {
                isBeingDragged = false;
                DOM.releaseCapture(getElement());
            }
        }
    }

    protected boolean isCursorResize(Event event) {
        int cursor = event.getClientY();
        int initial = getAbsoluteTop();
        int height = getOffsetHeight();
        return initial + height - 20 < cursor && cursor <= initial + height;
    }

    protected boolean isCursorMove(Event event) {
        int cursor = event.getClientY();
        int initial = movingPanelElement.getAbsoluteTop();
        int height = movingPanelElement.getOffsetHeight();
        return initial <= cursor && cursor <= initial + height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just look here: http://code.google.com/p/resizepanel/
There is a fully functional example for FF/IE/GChrome

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers, you can solve this independently of GWT. Much easier and cleaner. Just use the CSS3 [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/resize) property, and specify an [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) value other than the default (`visible`).

Note that you'll probably want to override the `resize` property for child elements so they don't all inherit resize-handles.

In my case, I have something like this in my `.ui.xml` file:

```xml
<g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames="myTableContainer">
    <g:ScrollPanel>
        <g:FlexTable ui:field="myTable"></g:FlexTable>
    </g:ScrollPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

And something like this in my stylesheet (GWT adds some extra divs, so you may need to adjust selectors to work for your case):

```css
.myTableContainer div {
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
}

.myTableContainer div div {
    resize: none;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

This gives my `FlexTable` a resize handle in the bottom-right corner, like this:

[image: Resize handle]

Users can drag the handle down to vertically resize the panel containing my `FlexTable`. Of course, instead of `vertical`, you can also allow resizing to be `horizontal` or `both`.

If you prefer doing things programmatically to the UiBinder way, I'm sure you can adapt it by simply adding the appropriate styles to your elements in the code.

Downsides? Doesn't work in IE/Edge (hey, I said *modern* browsers... and *CSS3*), but in [most others](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [GWT-Ext](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-ext/) widget extensions contains what you want in its [Resizable Panel](http://gwt-ext.com/demo/#resizablePanel)

Comment: I am not using gwt-ext,just gwt is my way ,I think dom manipulating can do it

Answer (score 0):

For the code above in onBrowserEvent(...) dont forget inserting

```
 event.preventDefault();
```

or you will have troubles with firefox image dragging!